# How to plot an array using a for loop?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot inside a `for` loop. I tried the following code also used `hold on` but the plot is still blank. I don't know where I am getting wrong.

```matlab
M2 = true(21, 6);
M2(1:2, 3:5) = false;

R = [0.5:0.1:2.5];
H=[0:5:25];
m=21,
n=6,
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n        
        if M(i,j)==0
            plot(H(i),R(j), 'color', 'r')
            drawnow();
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: try `plot(H(i),R(j), 'r.')`. You are plotting individual points. Plot expect lines. Unless you tell it that its a point to draw (the dot after red), it will try to draw a line, but a line with 1 point is invisible

Answer (score 1):

As Ander Biguri already said, the `plot` function actually does not draw anything when you provide only one point and do not specify any markers.

But, if you want to create some animated plot, that one of the points is displayed at a time:

```
h = scatter(0, 0, 'r');
xlim([min(H) max(H)]);
ylim([min(R) max(R)]);
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        if M(i,j)==0
            set(h, 'xdata', H(i), 'ydata', R(j));
            pause(0.5);
            drawnow();
        end
    end
end
```

Or if you want to show all point together, you don't even need a loop:

```
[HH, RR] = meshgrid(H, R);
scatter(HH(~M), RR(~M), 'r');
xlim([min(H) max(H)]);
ylim([min(R) max(R)]);
```